# Firestore read timestamp field -> undefined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I try to read two fields of a firestore document:

- Type is number { personScoresAllCount : 2 }
- Type is timestamp: { personScoresCalculationDate : 30/12/2021 12:00:00 AM }

[image]

These two fields are addressed by these 2 almost identical lines of code:

```
console.log("querySnapshotPersonsDocs[i].data().personScoresCalculationDate : "+JSON.stringify(querySnapshotPersonsDocs[i].data().personScoresCalculationDate ));
console.log("querySnapshotPersonsDocs[i].data().personScoresAllCount: "+JSON.stringify(querySnapshotPersonsDocs[i].data().personScoresAllCount));
```

Screenshot of the console:
While the second line returns the value like expected, the first line returns only 'undefined'.
[image]

What am I missing to adress the timestamp field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a whitespace at the end of the key-string! In the screenshot it is visible in form of the space between the key-string and the colon.

[image: screenshot from firestore]